# Text truncates when exporting a report to PDF format from Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

When exporting a report to PDF format from Crystal Reports, the text field truncated at the end of line.
kindly help me out,i have tried many solution but failed.image are attached here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn50I.png

Answer (score 0):

You reached the end of the page, either increase the margins ( Design - Page Setup) or lower the width of the field.